# Glob patterns to match all the files under one directory

Tags: javascript, glob

my file structure looks like this

```
  './app/routes',
  './app/routes/$.tsx',
  './app/routes/404.tsx',
  './app/routes/500.tsx',
  './app/routes/blog.category.$slug.tsx',
  './app/routes/blog.feed-$categoryOrAuthor-posts[.]xml.tsx',
  './app/routes/blog.feed[.]xml.tsx',
  './app/routes/blog.tsx',
  './app/routes/changelog.feed[.]xml.tsx',
  './app/routes/index-sitemap[.]xml.tsx',
  './app/routes/index.tsx',
  './app/routes/press.tsx',
  './app/routes/press/contact.tsx',
  './app/routes/sitemap-$locale[.]xml.tsx',
  './app/routes/sitemap[.]xml.tsx'
  './app/routes/locales/press.tsx',
  './app/routes/locales/press/contact.tsx',
```

I would like to write a glob patterns that match all the files under `/routes` directory but ignore files under `/routes/locales`. How could I do that?

I have try `./app/routes/**[!_locales]`but it ignores my subfolders

```
'./app/routes/press/contact.tsx',
```

Comment: Consider using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob to test your globs?

Comment: I use that as well but don't know how to write the correct pattern

Comment: I'm not convinced this can be done in one glob https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036787/glob-pattern-full-directory-except-sub-folders